# Order not work in elastic search aggregation when use partition

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, pagination, aggregation, bucket

How can I create pagination in elastic search  aggregation like bellow.
"CONTACT_ID" is not unique in all of my documents, since I have document with same ID and several parts.

So I have to use aggregation to create pagination and top_hits to get documents. but when I use partition, order not correct.

I have an aggregation like this.

```
  "aggregations": {
    "CONTACT_ID": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "CONTACT_ID",
        "size": 1000,
        "order": {
          "_key": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "DOCUMENTS": {
          "top_hits": {
            "from": 0,
            "size": 1,
            "version": false,
            "seq_no_primary_term": false,
            "explain": false,
            "sort": [
              {
                "_id": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

with the output

```
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884276
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884262
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884240
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884190
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884178
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884166
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884164
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884142
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884140
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884128
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884106
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884104
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884092
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884090
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884088
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884034
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884032
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884008
```

All documents are sorted based on ID
but when I used partition, order not work

```
      "terms": {
        "field": "CONTACT_ID",
        "size": 1000,
        "order": {
          "_key": "desc"
        },
        "include": {
          "partition": 0,
          "num_partitions": 2
        }
      },
```

output is

```
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884276
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884262
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884240
**[CONTACT_ID] => 367884166** --> not in the order
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884142
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884140
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884128
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884106
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884104
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884090
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884034
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884008
```

documents with

```
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884190
[CONTACT_ID] => 367884178
```

are in my next partition and order is not correct.

Comment: Hi did you find any solution for this?